# If Statement Within A Nested Array

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to do is query a WordPress custom post type using meta keys from a search form. The search form takes user inputs and show the results based on the matching criteria, Some of the form's fields might be blank, so I need to make sure I don't pass any blank value to the query argument. I need to use if within the arguments array.

I'll be grateful for any type of help.

This is the code I am using, but getting an error message.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ')'`

Here is my code:

```
        if (isset($POST['stock']) && !empty($POST['stock'])) {
            $stock = $POST['stock'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['mineral']) && !empty($POST['mineral'])) {
            $mineral = $POST['mineral'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['species']) && !empty($POST['species'])) {
            $species = $POST['species'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['color']) && !empty($POST['color'])) {
            $color = $POST['color'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['chemicalclass']) && !empty($POST['chemicalclass'])) {
            $chemicalclass = $POST['chemicalclass'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['locality']) && !empty($POST['locality'])) {
            $locality = $POST['locality'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['description']) && !empty($POST['description'])) {
            $description = $POST['description'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['size']) && !empty($POST['size'])) {
            $size = $POST['size'];
        }
        if (isset($POST['pricegt'])) {
            $pricegt = $POST['pricegt'];
        } else {
            $pricegt = 0;
        }
        if (isset($POST['pricelt'])) {
            $pricelt = $POST['pricelt'];
        } else {
            $pricelt = 999999;
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'products',
            'productspecies'    => $species,
            'localities'        => $locality,
            'meta_query' => array(
                //'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'value' => array( $pricegt, $pricelt ),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                ),
                if ($mineral) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_components',
                    'value' => $mineral,
                ),
                }
                if ($stock) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_lotnum',
                    'value' => $stock,
                ),
                }
                if ($color) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_color',
                    'value' => $color,
                ),
                }
                if ($description) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_smalldesc',
                    'value' => $description,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                }
                if ($size) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_size',
                    'value' => $size,
                ),
                }
                if ($chemicalclass) {
                array(
                    'key' => '_chemicalclass',
                    'valeu' => $chemicalclass,
                ),
                }
            ),
            );
    ?>
        <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <div class="postcount">We Found A Total Of <span><?php echo $query->post_count;?></span> Items Maching Your Search</div>

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you used these `if` inside the array?

Comment: Which line? Also try removing the last , from the ) just before the <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

Comment: Off-topic: shouldn't `$POST` be `$_POST`?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius We can't be sure if he is using a `$POST` variable, but you're probably right.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius yes, it should be $_POST. I am sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to pass `if` statements as arguments to the `array()` function. PHP does not allow that. One thing you can do is build the array without the optional parts and then add them later if necessary:

```
if ($stock) {
    $args['metaquery'][] = array(
        'key' => '_lotnum',
        'value' => $stock
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert instructions in the array initialization code.

Do it this way:

```
$args = array();

if (something){
    $args['metaquery'][] = array(contentsOfTheInnerArray);
}
if (something2){
    $args['metaquery'][] = array(contentsOfTheInnerArray2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if this works (in php that is) but you can do something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'price' => isset($POST['pricegt']) ? $POST['pricegt'] : 0,
    ...
);
```